# number of different sequences

Tags: combinatorics

He, let consider Basketball. We can make throw for 1, 2 or 3 points.

For example for 5 points we have throws sequences like:

```
{3, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 3} {1, 3, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}.
```

How can compute it for any **n**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $r \in \mathbb{R},$ let $\lfloor r\rfloor$ denote the *floor* of $r$ (i.e. the largest integer $\leq r).$

Compute $$A = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor.$$

For $a \in \{0,1,2,\cdots, A\}$, let $T_a$ denote the set of all sequences that use exactly $a$ occurrences of **3**.

The following algorithm will let you specify $T_a$.

For each $a$, compute $$B_a = \left\lfloor \frac{n - 3a}{2}\right\rfloor.$$

Then for each $b$ in $\{0,1,2,\cdots, B_a\}$, you can form a complete sequence consisting of

- $a$ **3**'s
- $b$ **2**'s
- $(n - 3a - 2b)$ **1**'s.

Note:
Although not requested, if instead you are looking for a **count** of the number of distinct sequences:

$$\sum_{a = 0}^A (B_a + 1).$$

**Edit** 
I just realized that the OP is construing $(3,2)$ and $(2,3)$ as different sequences.  The remedy for the above work is as follows:

Given a sequence of $a$ **3**'s, $b$ **2**'s, and 
$c = (n - 3a - 2b)$ **1**'s, let $t = a+b+c.$

Then the number of sequences that can be **permuted** from the **combination** of $a$ **3**'s, $b$ **2**'s and
$c$ **1**'s is:

$$\binom{T}{a} \times \binom{T-a}{b}$$.

Consequently, the formula for the count of the number of permuted sequences is $\{$setting $f(a,b) = a + b + (n - 3a - 2b)\}$:

$$\sum_{a = 0}^A \sum_{b = 0}^{B_a}\left[\binom{f(a,b)}{a} \times \binom{f(a,b)-a}{b}\right] .$$

Comment: Wow, just amazing. You are amazing!

Comment: @Zawada Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

Call $S_n$ the number if sequences of $n$ points.

For $1$ point, you have just one sequence, $(1)$.

For $2$ points, you have two sequences, $(2)$ and $(1,1)$.

For $3$ points, you have 4 sequences, $(3),(2,1),(1,2),(1,1,1)$.

So, $S_1=1, S_2=2, S_3=4$. Now let $n\geq4$. A sequence of $n$ points follows one of these cases:

$\bullet$ It begins by 1 and it´s followed by a sequence of $n-1$ points. ($S_{n-1}$ sequences)

$\bullet$ It begins by 2 and it´s followed by a sequence of $n-2$ points. ($S_{n-2}$ sequences)

$\bullet$ It begins by 3 and it´s followed by a sequence of $n-3$ points. ($S_{n-3}$ sequences)

Thus, we have that $S_n=S_{n-1}+S_{n-2}+S_{n-3}$. Thus, your the number of sequences of $n$ points is given by the  recursion:

$S(1)=1;S(2)=2;S(3)=4;S(n)=S(n-1)+S(n-2)+S(n-3)$.

This is a standard linear recurrence relation that can be solved for a explicit formula. If you want to try and solve it explicitly (the formula you obtain won´t be nice, to say the least), there is more info [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearRecurrenceEquation.html).

Comment: Do you disagree with the analysis in my answer?

Comment: I don´t know, I didn´t read it completely. I just didn´t see the recursion approach used to calculate the number of sequences and I thought it was a natural way to do it, so I answered the question explaining that way to find it.